# Can't open a folder by double click in win 7

Tags: windows-7

I had a problem: my folders and files did not open with a double click. I found here the answer to the question, but the description was not very detailed, and I could not use the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution to this question elsewhere and I want to share this with you.

Go to "Start Menu" click "Run" and type "regedit" (without typing "")
Click on HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
Click on Directory
Click on shell
Go to the window to the right
Double Click on "Default" ..... or .... with Right Click on "Default" and Select "Modify"
Then you will get the option "Value Data". Type there "none" (without typing "") and Click OK.
Refresh your desktop. Now you can open folders With Double Click.
It helped me to solve the problem, hope it may help to other people, too.

Comment: This is just a duplicate answer from the duplicate question.